# Referencing array values within nested objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Ve5ZQ/6/

I am attempting to reference the x value in the [x,y] pairs within chartGPS.series[0].data to determine the largest value of x currently in the series. However, it appears that I am referencing an undefined value for comparison.

'data' appears to be an array of arrays, so iterating through its pairs should be allowed with:

```
var lastUpdate = 0;
var theSeries = chartGPS.series[0].data;

// Loop to determine last updated timestamp (x value)
for (var i in theSeries) {
    // I think theSeries[i][0] should be the x value for each pair        
    alert(theSeries[i]); // Always alerts "undefined"             

    if (theSeries[i][0] > lastUpdate) {                
        lastUpdate = theSeries[i][0];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `console.log(theSeries[i]);` within your loop you can see that each index of the `theSeries` array has a property `x`:

```
for (var i in theSeries) {
    // I think theSeries[i][0] should be the x value for each pair
    alert(theSeries[i]);                
    if (theSeries[i][0] > lastUpdate) {                
        lastUpdate = theSeries[i][0];
    }
}
```

Changes to:

```
for (var i = 0, len = theSeries.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(theSeries[i]);                
    if (theSeries[i].x > lastUpdate) {                
        lastUpdate = theSeries[i].x;
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ve5ZQ/8/

Here is a sample object in your array (each line is a different property, some properties have sub-properties):

```
-> Aa
--> _high: 809
--> category: 5326
--> clientX: 736.7
--> config: Array[2]
--> graphic: pa
--> plotX: 736.7
--> plotY: 55.4
--> pointAttr: Array[0]
--> series: c
--> x: 5326
--> y: 73
--> yBottom: null
--> __proto__: Object
```

This was copied from my console via the above JSFiddle, notice that it has a `console.log(theSeries[i])` line inside the loop.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! Does that mean that theSeries[i] is an associative array or object created by the HC lib? Also, any suggestions for being able to more easily recognize this situation in the future?

Comment: @Conor **1.** `theSeries` is an array where each index is an object that holds several properties. **2.** Use `console.log()`, not `alert()`. Also use a browser that likes developers (basically not IE...) because the Chrome/Firefox developer tools seem to do a much better job than IE's native developer tools. When using `console.log()` you will be able to see all the data for an object/element. This is generally my first step with dealing with an object I didn't make myself, `console.log()` the object to see it's structure, then create my code based on the structure of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `theSeries[i].x` as theSeries[i] is an actual object with properies like x, y etc...

Comment: Thanks. I got caught thinking that since series is defined as "series: [[],[],[]]", then the ['s indicate arrays. I'm assuming this is not always the case with javascript? What led you to notice that the x,y pairs were objects and not arrays of length 2?

Answer (score 0):

See the answer by @CMS to the question [Loop through array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript). It's very thoroughly explained there why for in should not be used with arrays.